# ScreenPointToRay always going to (0, 0, 0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm doing an incredibly simple raycast, copied almost directly from the docs themselves, but the raycast hit always goes to the world origin (0, 0, 0). The only caveat is that I'm using the new(ish) input system, but as far as I can tell that shouldn't make a difference.

My code is dead simple:

```cs
Vector3 mousePos = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue(); // Debug shows an appropriate value being returned from input system

RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos);

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
    Debug.DrawLine(mainCamera.transform.position, hit.transform.position); // Always goes from Camera to 0, 0, 0
}
```

It's honestly so simple I'm not even sure where else to look, and it's driving me crazy. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Just checked your code in 2019.4.1f1 with *Input System* package v 1.0.0 and it seems correct. Only have replaced your

```
Debug.DrawLine(mainCamera.transform.position, hit.transform.position);
```

with

```
Debug.DrawLine(Camera.main.transform.position, hit.transform.position);
```

Try to check if you have a camera with "MainCamera" tag in the scene.

[image: Raycasting]

Comment: Thanks for your reply; you were definitely right that there was a discrepancy there :)
This actually led me down a different path which identified the problem: it's because I was using hit.transform.position, when really I wanted hit.point. Turns out I was always return 0, 0, 0, because that was the origin of the _floor_.

Thanks for your help!